# Simple Alfresco Share CMIS query collection not working

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I have a simple CMIS query which I am executing from within a collection folder. The purpose is to retrieve two specific documents placed in two different folders.

```
SELECT d.* FROM cmis:document d JOIN ws:webasset w ON w.cmis:objectId = d.cmis:objectId 
WHERE 
   (d.cmis:name = 'name1.html' AND in_folder(d,'${section:/root/folder1}'))
OR
   (d.cmis:name = 'name2.html' AND in_folder(d,'${section:/root/folder2}'))
```

I also gave a try to:

```
SELECT d.* FROM cmis:document d JOIN ws:webasset w ON w.cmis:objectId = d.cmis:objectId 
WHERE 
   (d.cmis:name = 'name1' OR d.cmis:name = 'name2.html') 
AND 
   (in_folder(d,'${section:/root/folder1}') OR in_folder(d,'${section:/root/folder2}'))
```

but they are not retrieving any documents. If I am executing just (name1 in folder1) alone it correctly retrieve the document 'name1'.
Am I missing some fundamental from CMIS language ?

Related question: I used to execute this type of query directly from the collection folder, due to the presence of `in_folder()` or `in_tree()` with the addition of `$section` instruction, which are not working in node browser. Is there a way to execute this in node browser ?

**UPDATE**
Typo error: the queries above were missing the qualifier `d`, which is mandatory when there is a join in the query. Just an error, the original query I am executing does have the qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a CMIS object ID with in_folder. It does not accept a path. See the spec at http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html

Comment: But ${section} is supposed to return the id. Isn'it ? I am using it succesfully everywhere in all my dynamic collections. However I also gave a try to hard coding the object id but it is not working too. Why does it work fine when I look in one folder only using ${section} ?

Comment: I am not familiar with $section. More info?

Comment: Well, it is not specified as it should in the official doc. The only reasonable option, based also on the many collections I have, is that it returns the section id.

Comment: See this: [Configuring a dynamic asset collection](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/qs-configure-dynamic.html)

Comment: Aha, you are using Web Quick Start. The docs say that if you want to reference /root/blog you would use $section:/blog. Your paths include /root. Try $section:/folder1 instead.